# How to use SmileysParser in yiichat with same time on YII

Tags: php, yii

i use smileyParser extension

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.smileys.SmileysParser');
$content="O:-) test ;)";
$content=SmileysParser::parse($content,'default');
echo $content;
```

and output:

[image: it works]

but now, how to combine with yiichat
[image: output in yiichat]